# Joomla 3 Module Save Event

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, module

I am searching for an event that is triggered after saved a specific Module, for a Plugin. Like the onContentAfterSave Event for the Content Group.

Is there such an Event, or how can I trigger such an event after save?

Answer (score 2):

On the module you should create a dispatcher in its save method like this:

```
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger( 'onAfterMyModuleSave', array( $myModuleData, $insertid ) );
```

You can include any kind of data that you would like to handle in your plugin with an array like the example.

Then at your plugin you have to create a "listener" like this:

```
public function onAfterMyModuleSave($data, $id)
{
  //do what you like here
}
```

Of course I recommend you first to check for any existing dispatchers in the module