# Is there any equivalent event to onContentAfterSave for Modules?

Tags: module, plugin

Is there a way we can 'listen' to the module save event so that we can use a plugin to do some additional work. I found [this question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/12252/112) on stack overflow but I am confused as to where dispatcher will be created?

What I am trying to do is to create a plugin that will automatically resize any images that was saved for a module by running the code every time someone saves the module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Administrator Modules component fires **onExtensionAfterSave**, context com_modules.module.